# Troubleshooting kubernetes removed pod

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have a problem with spark application on kuberenetes. Spark driver tries to create an executor pod and executor pod fails to start. The problem is that as soon as the pod fails, spark driver removes it and creates a new one. The new one fails dues to the same reason. So, how can i recover logs from already removed pods as it seems like default spark behavior on kubernetes. Also, i am not able to catch the pods since the removal is instantaneous. I have to wonder how i am ever supposed to fix the failing pod issue if i cannot recover the errors.

Comment: This may involve "container-level" debugging. Could you post the pod specification? Maybe we can set up a `kubectl run` command to get more insight.

Comment: Anything useful returned by `kubectl get events`?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be helpful to implement cluster logging. Even if the pod gets restarted or deleted, its logs will stay in a log aggregator storage.

There are more than one solution to the [cluster logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#cluster-level-logging-architectures), but most popular is EFK (Elasticsearch, Fluentd, Kibana).

Actually, you can go even without Elasticsearch and Kibana.
Check out an excellent article [Application Logging in Kubernetes with fluentd by Rosemary Wang](https://medium.com/@joatmon08/application-logging-in-kubernetes-with-fluentd-4556f1573672) that explains how to configure `fluentd` to put aggregated logs to `fluentd` pod `stdout` and access it later using the command:

```
kubectl logs <fluentd pod>…
```

Comment: How could you know that your log aggregator has processed the logs before they get deleted?